# Populating a DTO with a property list of DTO by using transform

Tags: nhibernate, list, entity, transform, dto

I have a entity called ActivityLog:

```
    public class ActivityLog : EntityModel<ActivityLog>
{
    public virtual int activityID { get; set; }
    public virtual int entityType { get; set; }
    public virtual int entityID { get; set; }
    public virtual string entityName { get; set; }
    public virtual int action { get; set; }
    public virtual int parentType { get; set; }
    public virtual int parentID { get; set; }
    public virtual string parentName { get; set; } }
    public virtual string userName { get; set; }
    public virtual int instanceID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? timeStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? groupTimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

and a DTO class called Activity:

```
    public class Activity
{
    public virtual int activityID { get; set; }
    public virtual int entityType { get; set; }
    public virtual int entityID { get; set; }
    public virtual string entityName { get; set; }
    public virtual int action { get; set; }
    public virtual int parentType { get; set; }
    public virtual int parentID { get; set; }
    public virtual string parentName { get; set; }
    public virtual string userName { get; set; }
    public virtual int instanceID { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? timeStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? groupTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public IList<Activity> activities { get; set; }
}
```

I need to fill DTO from Entity with transform also I want to fill `IList<Activity>` with the entities which have `parentType` and `parentID`. What is the best way to do it, with minimum query?

Comment: [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IList<ActivityLog> activityLogs = ...;

var activities = session.Query<Activity>()
    .WhereRestrictionOn(a => a.Parent.Id).IsIn(activityLogs.Select(al => al.parentID))
    .WhereRestrictionOn(a => a.Parent.Type).IsIn(activityLogs.Select(al => al.parentType))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToLookUp(a => new { ParentId = a.Parent.Id, ParentType = a.Parent.Type });

var results = activityLogs
    .Select(al => new ActivityDTO
    {
        activityID = al.activityID,
        entityType = al.entityType,
        ...
        activities = activities[new { ParentId = al.parentID, ParentType = al.parentType }].ToList()
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ProjectionList and an AliasToBean resulttransformer:

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria <ActivityLog>();
criteria.SetProjection (Projections.ProjectionList()
                                     .Add (Projections.Property ("activityID"), "activityID")
                                     ...);

criteria.SetResultTransformer (Transformers.AliasToBean <Activity>());

return criteria.List<Activity>();
```

Comment: i have tried this, but it does not work on `IList<Activity> activities` @Firo's answer looks more suitable. Thanks for answer.